# DTX file generates empty file

Tags: dtx

I recently gave the documentation of my `chscite` package a facelift for inclusion in CTAN, and was assuming that doing so wouldn't break anything. Unfortunately, I just discovered that the package doesn't work because the `.bst` file isn't being generated properly, and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I know that [this changeset](https://bitbucket.org/urdh/latexhax/changeset/9a8b41214e67) breaks it, but I can't figure out why. The full DTX file is [available on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chscite/chscite.dtx). What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look on it and found that the `.bib` file is created if the `\endinput` is removed from line 659. Note that `docstrip` adds it anyway by default and it is not really required.

This happened because `docstrip` explicitly looks for `\endinput` lines. If you indent it with a space it works as well. I would simply remove it from the DTX file.